# Dropdown menu is pushing other item (using display: flex)

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, responsive-design, position

i have a filtering menus using display: flex for it but if i click on them (Colour or Price) and the hidden items are shown its making the other items in the container to go up.
I tried to delete "justify-content" of the container (.filter in the code) and the problem no longer persists but then the items in the container are no longer centered.

```js
const hiddenMenu = document.querySelectorAll('.menu__box');
const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');

function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
    hiddenMenu.forEach(element => {
        element.classList.toggle("menuActive")
    });
    body[0].classList.toggle('stopScrolling');
  }


function filterDrop(className){
    let arrow = document.querySelectorAll('.arrow');
    if(className === ".list"){
        arrow[0].classList.toggle('down');
        arrow[0].classList.toggle('up');
    }
    else{
        arrow[1].classList.toggle('down');
        arrow[1].classList.toggle('up');
    }
    let element = document.querySelectorAll(className);
    element.forEach(el => {
        el.classList.toggle('hideList')
    });
}
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#header{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ECEFF1;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}

#hamContainer {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 100;
  margin-left: 24px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;

}

.change .bar1 {
  transform: translate(0, 11px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.change .bar2 {opacity: 0;}

.change .bar3 {
  transform: translate(0, -11px) rotate(45deg);
}

#logo{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.menu__box {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 80px 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ECEFF1;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}
.menu__item {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}
.menu__item:hover {
  background-color: #CFD8DC;
}

.menuActive{
  left: 0;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.stopScrolling{
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.categoryContainer{

  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  top: 104px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ECEFF1;
  border-top: 4px solid black;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
}

.categoryContainer > span:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.categoryContainer > span::after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  height: 1px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
}

.categoryContainer > span:hover::after{
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}

.filter{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #ECEFF1;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 205px);
  margin-top: 104px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.filter-content{
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 60px;
}


.arrow {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.down {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.up {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

#filter-colour, #filter-price{
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#filter-colour :nth-child(1), #filter-price :nth-child(1){
  cursor: pointer;
}

.list, .listPrice{
  display: none;
  font-weight:normal;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.list:hover, .listPrice:hover{
  background-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);
}

.list p, .listPrice p{
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 40px; 
}

.hideList{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Product Listing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <nav>
            <div id="header">
                   <div id="hamContainer" onclick="myFunction(this)">
                       <div class="bar1"></div>
                       <div class="bar2"></div>
                       <div class="bar3"></div>
                     </div>
                     <div id="logo">
                        <a href="index.html">
                            <img src="images/bucherer-logo-big.svg" alt="">
                        </a>
                     </div>
               
                   <ul class="menu__box">
                     <li><a class="menu__item" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                           <li><a class="menu__item" href="index.html">About</a></li>
                           <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Team</a></li>
                           <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                           <li><a class="menu__item" href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                   </ul>
            </div>
         </nav>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="categoryContainer">
            <span>ALL PRODUCTS</span>
            <span>WATCHES</span>
            <span>JEWELLERY</span>
         </div>

         <nav>
            <div class="filter">
                <div id="title" class="filter-content">Filter Products</div>

                <div id="filter-colour" class="filter-content">
                    <p  onclick="filterDrop('.list')">Colour <i class="arrow down"></i></p>
                    <div class="list">
                        <p>Black</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list">
                        <p>Blue</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list">
                        <p>Brown</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list">
                        <p>Silver</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list">
                        <p>Gold</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list">
                        <p>Pink</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list">
                        <p>Gold</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list">
                        <p>Multicolor</p>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div id="filter-price" class="filter-content">
                    <p  onclick="filterDrop('.listPrice')">Price <i class="arrow down"></i></p>
                    <div class="listPrice">
                        <p>0 - 499 EUR</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="listPrice">
                        <p>500 - 999 EUR </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="listPrice">
                        <p>1000 - 1499 EUR</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="listPrice">
                        <p>1500 - 1999 EUR</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="listPrice">
                        <p>2000 - 2499 EUR</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="listPrice">
                        <p>2500 - 2999 EUR</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
         </nav>
    </main>



    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What can i do?